# Relation between trace and norm in a quadratic field extension

Tags: algebraic-number-theory, field-trace

In the book of Y.Kitaoka about Arithmetic of quadratic forms page 12, I found these relations:
for a finite field $F$ and by considering the quadratic extension $F':=F(\theta)$
$$tr(x\bar{y})=N(x+y)-N(x)-N(y)$$
$$\forall x\in \overline{F'},\quad tr\left(x\overline{F'}\right)=0\implies x=0$$
where $\bar{y}$ denotes the conjugate of $y$  over $F$, $N$ and $tr$ are the norm and trace mapping from $F'$ to $F$. So my question as follows; how to prove this equality and this implication ?. I tried to express:
$$tr(x\bar{y})=\sum_{\sigma\in Gal(F'/F)}\sigma(x)\sigma(\bar{y})$$
and
\begin{align*}
N(x+y)&=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(F'/F)}\big(\sigma(x)+\sigma(\bar{y})\big)\\
&=\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(F'/F)}\sigma(x)+\prod_{\sigma\in Gal(F'/F)}\sigma(\bar{y})+\prod_{\sigma,\tau\in Gal(F'/F)}\sigma(x)\tau(\bar{y})\\
&=N(x)+N(\bar{y})+\prod_{\sigma,\tau\in Gal(F'/F)}\sigma(x)\tau(\bar{y})
\end{align*}

Comment: It is a quadratic extension. So just replace $N(x+y)$ by $(x+y)(\sigma(x)+\sigma(y))  $ and $Tr(x\sigma(y))$ by $x\sigma(y))+\sigma(x\sigma(y)))=x\sigma(y)+\sigma(x)y$.